# Rotate Bitmap around point and make that point the new center

Tags: c#, image, rotation, gdi+

I want to rotate a Bitmap around a given point and have that point become the new center of the Bitmap.
Here is what I tried first

```
        Bitmap rotate(Bitmap img, float angle, int cx, int cy)
        {
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
            int middleX = img.Width / 2,
                middleY = img.Height / 2;
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.Black);
                g.TranslateTransform(cx, cy);
                g.RotateTransform(angle);
                g.TranslateTransform(-cx, -cy);
                g.TranslateTransform(middleX - cx, middleY - cy); //shift (cx, cy) to be at the center, does not work
                g.DrawImage(originalImage, new Point(0, 0));
            }
            return result;
        }
```

But when I go to translate the image after rotation, the translation is in the original space instead of this new rotated space and doesn't come out right. 
I tried basically every combination of things I could think of with no luck. Search results only describe how to rotate around a point.

Original image (red dot is the point to rotate around) - 
[image]

After rotating by 45 degrees the image should be translated so that the red dot is the center of the image

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _"become the new center of the Bitmap"_. It would be best if you would provide small sample images, showing the "before" and "after" for your desired operation. Also, make sure you provide a good [mcve] that shows exactly what you've tried (if you provide an image, the MCVE need not include the bitmap data itself, since that would be available from the posted image).

Comment: First translate the point to the center, then do the rotation!

Comment: @TaW I tried that and it didn't work. When I get home again I can post the code I tried.

Comment: untested pseudo code: `translate(-red);translate(-center);rotate(angle);translate(center)`

Comment: I figured it out finally. You have to set the Matrix Order for the translation to the center. I tried translating to center then rotating and a million other things. No luck.

Comment: Not really. This `g.Clear(Color.Black);
    g.TranslateTransform(middleX, middleY);
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    g.TranslateTransform(-middleX, -middleY);
    g.TranslateTransform(middleX - cx,  middleY -cy);
    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);` will work as well..

Comment: That also works. For some reason I was thinking that rotating around any point other than (cx, cy) would not give me the right results. But really you can rotate around any point and the resulting angle of the image will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the matrix order to Append for the final translation. I have no idea why this is what makes it work. I literally just brute force tried every possible way of doing everything until it worked. I'd still be interested in an explanation of what is going on though.

```
    Bitmap rotate(Bitmap img, float angle, int cx, int cy)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
        int mx = img.Width / 2,
            my = img.Height / 2;
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            g.TranslateTransform(cx, cy);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            g.TranslateTransform(-cx, -cy);
            g.TranslateTransform(mx - cx, my - cy, MatrixOrder.Append);
            g.DrawImage(originalImage, new Point(0, 0));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to get thoroughly confused [read this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d47b9ff6-e58c-4a3a-9fc2-4ad874b837bd/graphics-transformation-and-matrixorder?forum=vbgeneral) ;-)